# How to format a date using Apache Derby?

Tags: java, date, derby

I would like to format nicely a date received from a query like:

```
SELECT recdate FROM myrecords;
```

pratically I am searching the function to pretty formatting with a date pattern,
better if SimpleDateFormat like. And if not possible how can I build a class for formatting
with somtehing like:

```
SELECT MyFormatter(recdate) FROM myrecords
```

Answer (score 2):

Look here:

[DateFormat and SimpleDateFormat Examples](http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/)

Sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Get the Date object that comes from DerbyDB...
    //Date derbyDate = YOUR DATE FIELD HERE

    // Make a SimpleDateFormat for toString()'s output. This
    // has short (text) date, a space, short (text) month, a space,
    // 2-digit date, a space, hour (0-23), minute, second, a space,
    // short timezone, a final space, and a long year.
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");

    // See if we can parse the output of Date.toString()
    try
    {
        Date parsed = format.parse(derbyDate.toString());

        System.out.println(parsed.toString());
    }
    catch(ParseException pe)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot parse \"" + derbyDate.toString() + "\"");
    }
}
```

Comment: ^^ This. It also goes without saying that you (the OP) do not use Apache Derby (or any relational database system) to format the date. You use a formatter. 

You use Derby to pull the data with SQL, and you use a formatter to massage the date data and make it pretty.