# Convert date using Apache Derby

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, derby, date-format, simpledateformat

I have a date stored in a varchar field in the following format:

```
3 Jun 2016
```

I'd like to convert it to another varchar, this time in this format:

```
2016-06-03 00:00:00.000
```

The reason I need it in that second format is to interact with a certain API.

Ps. [This other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572568/how-to-format-a-date-using-apache-derby/38404977) is similar, but pertains to just formatting a field that is stored as a date in the database. My question is about converting a date stored as a string into another date stored as string.

Comment: It's a bit sad to get a down-vote after posting a question and answer (to share knowledge, Q&A-style)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a date using Apache Derby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572568/how-to-format-a-date-using-apache-derby). And a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25449472/642706).

Comment: Thanks Basil, those two questions are similar in the sense that they are about formatting dates. However mine is different because it's about working with dates stored as strings. Thanks for the research though

Comment: You should edit your question to be more clear, specify exactly what is the data type of the column and explain you have textual data stored in exactly what format that represents date values. And explain your goal. Do you really want the time-of-day?

Comment: Noted - question has been adjusted

Answer (score 2):

Apache Derby doesn't have a native function, but it's possible to create your own and call it from the database.

First, create the java method that will convert the date:

```
package DbExamples.StoredProcedures;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateUtilities {

    public static String convertDate(String inputDateString, String currentFormat, String outputFormatString) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(currentFormat);
        Date inputDate = inputFormat.parse(inputDateString);

        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputFormatString);
        String result = outputFormat.format(inputDate);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Then inject the jar file into the database by running the following sql statement on the database:

```
CALL SQLJ.REMOVE_JAR('App.StoredProcedures', 0);
CALL SQLJ.INSTALL_JAR('C:\dev\DbExamples\dist\DbExamples.jar', 'App.StoredProcedures', 0);
CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY('derby.database.classpath', 'App.StoredProcedures');
```

Now create the stored procedure in the database by running the following sql statement:

```
drop function convertDate;
create function convertDate(dateString varchar(8000), currentFormat varchar(8000), outputFormat varchar(8000))
returns varchar(8000)
parameter style java no sql
language java external name 'DbExamples.StoredProcedures.DateUtilities.convertDate';
```

Now you can run your query:

```
select
    convertDate('3 Jun 2016', 'd MMM yyyy', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') as dt
from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

Which returns:

```
2016-06-03 00:00:00.000
```

In fact, the technique can even be used to convert a varchar to a TIMESTAMP:

```
select
    cast(convertDate('3 Jun 2016', 'd MMM yyyy', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') as timestamp) as dt
from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```